# Django Rest Framework filtering a set of item to include only latest entry of each type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a list of object of this kind of structure returned in my api

```
SomeCustomModel => {
  itemId: "id",
  relatedItem: "id",
  data: {},
  created_at: "data string" 
}
```

I want to return a list that contains only unique relatedItemIds, filtered by the one that was created most recently.

I have written this and it seems to work

```
    id_tracker = {}
    query_set = SomeCustomModel.objects.all()
    for item in query_set:
        if item.relatedItem.id not in id_tracker:
            id_tracker[item.relatedItem.id] = 1
        else:
            query_set = query_set.exclude(id=item.id)
    return query_set
```

This works by I am wondering if there is cleaner way of writing this using only django aggregations.

I am using Mysql so the distinct("relatedItem") aggregation is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to do this within sql. You can use [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to accomplish this. Here's the example from the django docs.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter_email=Subquery(newest.values('email')[:1]))
```

Comment: I dont understand how this helps me sorry. Which part of that is doing the filtering to unique values?

Comment: The example above is getting the latest comment for each post. You want the latest `relatedItem` per `item` in `query_set`. Add an annotation to `query_set` that will use a `Subquery` for `relatedItem` to get the latest value.

Comment: yah see i dont know how to do that without using the distinct() aggregation. 
And I cant do that without losing all my original id information

Comment: It easy to do in the documentation example because they only want to get one latest value. But I need to get the latest value for  each unique id.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the information you've provided in your question. You'd need to add the actual `query_set` definition and the models involved.

Comment: I have added a model and query set definition

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that can replace distict() in a django-esque manner. However, you could do something along the lines of:

```
list(set(map(lambda x: x.['relatedItem_id'], query_set.order_by('created_at').values('relatedItem_id'))))
```

or

```
list(set(map(lambda x: x.relatedItem_id, query_set.order_by('created_at'))))
```

which are a bit more Pythonic.

However, you are saying that you want to return a list yet your function returns a queryset. Which is the valid one?

Comment: I was using list in the abstract sense. QuerySet is fine